# insert query for combo boxes

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me out in inserting data to database in this situation.

I have a form that has drop down and a list box(multiple/ combo).  What needs to happen is we select a value from the dropdown and select a bunch of values from list box and we click submit, then all the data has to go to DB in this way

Say we have 1,2 in dorpdown and 1,2,3,4,5,6 in list box.

- Then we select 1 in dropdown and 2,4 in list box.
- The DB needs to store it as 1,2 and 1.4 in different rows. I dont want to have multiple insert queries here.

It will be great if someone can help me achieve in a single query.(This is a weird try but jus giving a chance to make it work.)

Comment: What are you using to build the UI? WPF? WinForms? WebForms? MVC?

Comment: I am doing in java.. MSSQL is the DB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vb.net, this would be the best scenario

```
        Dim strquery As String = ""
        For Each myitem As ListItem In datalist1.Items
            If myitem.Selected Then
                strquery &= "insert into mytable(ID,name) values (" & dropdownlist1.selecteditem.value & "," & myitem.Value & ")"
            End If
        Next
```

If you are using c#:

```
string strquery = "";
foreach (ListItem myitem in datalist1.Items) {
    if (myitem.Selected) {
        strquery += "insert into mytable(ID,name) values (" + dropdownlist1.selecteditem.value + "," + myitem.Value + ")";
    }
}
```

off course after this step you will have to make a connection to the database and this strquery should be your commandtext.

Comment: I am using java.. But I dont want to use any loping concept.. I want make a plain insert statement directly.. if possible..

Comment: you are not doing any loop in the database, you are looping ur sql statement so that you insert them at once.